# httpx.WriteTimeout using dracoon in python for large data upload

Tags: python, upload, timeout, python-asyncio, timeoutexception

I am currently using a python upload script to a dataspace with the library dracoon. I use this script on ubuntu 20.04 inside a docker container (base image ubuntu 20.04). I tested it with small data files and all worked fine. I started testing it with large video files (approximately 100 video files which have in total 500 GB). And now I get a connection error.

Here is my code

```
from dracoon import DRACOON, OAuth2ConnectionType
import asyncio
import glob
import os

async def main():

    baseURL = 'https://dataspace.keba.com'
    client_id = 'XXX'
    client_secret = 'XXX'

    dracoon = DRACOON(base_url=baseURL, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)

    username = 'XX'
    password = 'XX' # use getpass.getpass() in interactive scripts

    connection = await dracoon.connect(OAuth2ConnectionType.password_flow, username, password)
    
    target = '/Test_upload/' # encrypted nodes supported

    files = glob.glob("/data/*")

    for file in files:
        await dracoon.upload(file_path=file, target_path=target)

    await dracoon.logout() # log out (revoke tokens)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

and this is the error message:

```
Connection error.
https://0-2754873549.s3.nbg01.de.dracoon.io/6/57a-c4c/000000d-up200001966-50326e4a5973594f4a544d6b564f7654?uploadId=2~0r71KblRyls7z72lC6byPDPqWJhtNrk&partNumber=2&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230221T142520Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-length%3Bhost&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Credential=R5NLJ5I1FCBUPCUR0Y11%2F20230221%2Feu-central-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e005fdec5882a0c13d0321ac5fed5945567ccfca48a9e974bc63215572a3e20d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/backends/asyncio.py", line 51, in write
    await self._stream.send(item=buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 202, in send
    await self._call_sslobject_method(self._ssl_object.write, item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 168, in _call_sslobject_method
    await self.transport_stream.send(self._write_bio.read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 1307, in send
    await self._protocol.write_event.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/locks.py", line 309, in wait
    await fut
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 10, in map_exceptions
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/backends/asyncio.py", line 51, in write
    await self._stream.send(item=buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/anyio/_core/_tasks.py", line 118, in __exit__
    raise TimeoutError
TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 60, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 353, in handle_async_request
    resp = await self._pool.handle_async_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 253, in handle_async_request
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 237, in handle_async_request
    response = await connection.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 90, in handle_async_request
    return await self._connection.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_async/http11.py", line 112, in handle_async_request
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_async/http11.py", line 82, in handle_async_request
    await self._send_request_body(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_async/http11.py", line 135, in _send_request_body
    await self._send_event(event, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_async/http11.py", line 144, in _send_event
    await self._network_stream.write(bytes_to_send, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/backends/asyncio.py", line 51, in write
    await self._stream.send(item=buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpcore/_exceptions.py", line 14, in map_exceptions
    raise to_exc(exc)
httpcore.WriteTimeout

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload.py", line 37, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "upload.py", line 31, in main
    await dracoon.upload(file_path=file, target_path=target)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dracoon/__init__.py", line 284, in upload
    upload = await self.nodes.upload_s3_unencrypted(file_path=file_path, upload_channel=upload_channel, file_name=file_name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tenacity/_asyncio.py", line 88, in async_wrapped
    return await fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tenacity/_asyncio.py", line 47, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 314, in iter
    return fut.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tenacity/_asyncio.py", line 50, in __call__
    result = await fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dracoon/nodes/__init__.py", line 621, in upload_s3_unencrypted
    await self.dracoon.handle_connection_error(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dracoon/client/__init__.py", line 300, in handle_connection_error
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dracoon/nodes/__init__.py", line 613, in upload_s3_unencrypted
    res = await self.dracoon.uploader.put(url=upload_url, content=chunk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1885, in put
    return await self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1533, in request
    return await self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1620, in send
    response = await self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1648, in _send_handling_auth
    response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1685, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = await self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1722, in _send_single_request
    response = await transport.handle_async_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 353, in handle_async_request
    resp = await self._pool.handle_async_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions
    raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
httpx.WriteTimeout
```

As I used the script the first time on my Ubuntu device it uploaded the first few video files before the exception arose. As I try it now, no file at all is uploaded. Does anybody has a hint for me, whats going wrong here?
Authentication was successfull, I checked the connection with a print statement. Access_token_validity is set to 28000 - so this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Any chance you had hit any limit - upload or space, or your target platform?  Or maybe even a cap on your internet connection itself? This seems very likely.

Comment: Thank you for the hint - I will check that